# How to create a module to allow for multiple instances of the same module with different variable parameters

Tags: blocks

How do you create a module to allow for multiple instances of the same module block with different variable parameters. I know how to create global parameters but that will apply to that block across the site.

this is an image of opening up the settings for the block on the panel[image: this is an image of opening up the settings for the block on the panel]

Answer (score 1):

Generate your blocks same way block module does: appending an id. Then store your configuration indexed by this id. You can store your values in a custom table (see schema api and install file syntax) or in the variable table (using variable_get() and variable_set()).

Whenever an operation with a block happens you receive the block id. Use the block id to access or set your configuration data. For example, the code for rendering a block should be the same for all your custom blocks, but you feed that code with different configurations that you read from your custom table or variable table using the provided block id.

Comment: very cool, I will do that. Is it a specific menu hook that I need to use to have this property show up when a user clicks settings within the panel?

Comment: Yes, use hook_block_configure:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_configure/7

Keep in mind that what I've called id is the delta parameter. Also, check other block hooks (view, info, save, etc)

Comment: This works for setting usettings in the block page but when I go to a panel and hit the settings on the content it still only shows the title as editable. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I think that question is more related to Panels, but I'm not used to panels. Check for existing Panels hooks that allow you to change those settings.

Comment: Ok thanks, someone mentioned creation a c tools plugin.